# Locking to make a class threadsafe with a C# example or is this class threadsafe?

Tags: c#, locking, thread-safety

I am trying to investigate locking to create a threadsafe class and have a couple of questions.  Given the following class:

```
    public class StringMe 
    {
        protected ArrayList  _stringArrayList = new ArrayList();
        static readonly object _locker = new object();

        public void AddString(string stringToAdd)
        {
            lock (_locker) _stringArrayList.Add(stringToAdd);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
return string.Join(",",string[])_stringArrayList.ToArray(Type.GetType("System.String")));
            }
        }
    }
```

1) Did I successfully make AddString andToString threadsafe?

2) In the ToString method I've created is it necessary to lock there to make it threadsafe?

3) Is it only the methods that modify data that need to be locked or do both the read and write opperations need to be locked to make it threadsafe?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: The `_locker` does not have to be (should not be) static .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you haven't made those calls thread-safe - because the `_stringArrayList` field is protected. Subclasses could be doing whatever they like with it while `AddString` and `ToString` are being called.

For example (as the other answers claim that your code *is* thread-safe.)

```
public class BadStringMe : StringMe
{
    public void FurtleWithList()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            _stringArrayList.Add("Eek!");
            _stringArrayList.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
BadStringMe bad = new BadStringMe();
new Thread(bad.FurtleWithList).Start();
bad.AddString("This isn't thread-safe");
```

Prefer private fields - it makes it easier to reason about your code.

Additionally:

- Prefer `List<T>` to `ArrayList` these days
- You're locking with a *static* variable for some reason... so even if you've got several instances of `StringMe`, only one thread can be in `AddString` at a time *in total*
- Using `typeof(string)` is much cleaner than `Type.GetType("System.String")`

> 3) Is it only the methods that modify data that need to be locked or do both the read and write opperations need to be locked to make it threadsafe?

All, assuming that there might be *some* operations. If *everything* is just reading, you don't need any locks - but otherwise your reading threads could read two bits of data from the data structure which have been modified in between, even if there's only one *writing* thread. (There are also memory model considerations to bear in mind.)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you so much.  This clears it up for me very nicely. +1, more if I could!

Answer (score 4):

> 1) Did I successfully make AddString andToString threadsafe?

Yes, If you change `_stringArrayList` to be private

> 2) In the ToString method I've created is it necessary to lock there to make it threadsafe?

Yes

> 3) Is it only the methods that modify data that need to be locked or do both the read and write opperations need to be locked to make it threadsafe?

Read and write.

Comment: Readers must lock also- if you only lock writers the data can change underneath readers, and that can cause exceptions.  See http://www.dotnetperls.com/invalidoperationexception

Answer (score 3):

Yes to all three (i.e. read/write to the last).

But there is more:

You make your lock object `static`, while the data you protect is a per instance field. That means that all instances of `StringMe` are protected against each other, event though they have distinct data (i.e. instances of `_stringArrayList`). For the example you give, you can remove the `static` modifier from `_locker`. To be more precise, you typically define a "lock" for a set of data, or yet better *invariants*, you want to preserve. So usually, the lifetime (and scope) of the lock should equal that of the data.

Also, for good measure, you should not have a higher visibility on the data you protect than on the lock. In your example, a derived implementation could alter `_stringArrayList` (since it is protected) without acquiring the lock, thus breaking the invariant. I would make them both `private` and, if you must, only expose `_stringArrayList` through (properly locking) methods to derived classes.